# Drive won't map in Java if there is whitespace in name

Tags: java, mapping, drive

I'm trying to map a drive in Java.  Code runs fine, the drive just isn't mapped.

```
zing =  "M: \\\\Ds-file2-2\\Quality Archive";
String command = "c:\\windows\\system32\\net.exe use " + zing;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

I've tried to map other folders on that server and they work.  I've tried mapping
the drive in windows and that works.  I tried mapping another folder with spaces and it failed.  I thought that the quotes would capture the space in the name.  No
errors occur.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this: `zing =  "\"M: \\\\Ds-file2-2\\Quality Archive\"";`.  This translates to `"M: \\Ds-file2-2\Quality Archive"`, which is what you want the command to run, right?

Comment: @Pokechu22: Tried this and it did not work :\  Thanks for the comment though!

Comment: The joke is on you TC, the line you generate wouldn't work in cmd either.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you want the quotes surrounding the string to appear when the command is executed.  But you aren't actually adding quotes.  In the current state, `command` is `c:\\windows\\system32\\net.exe use M: \\\\Ds-file2-2\\Quality Archive`.  I assume you want it to be `c:\\windows\\system32\\net.exe use "M: \\\\Ds-file2-2\\Quality Archive"`.

In that case, change `zing` to `zing = "\"M: \\\\Ds-file2-2\\Quality Archive\"".  This is escaping the quotes with`\"`, and thus`command`becomes`c:\windows\system32\net.exe use "M: \\Ds-file2-2\Quality Archive"`.

Your code above would become this:

```
zing =  "\"M: \\\\Ds-file2-2\\Quality Archive\"";
String command = "c:\\windows\\system32\\net.exe use " + zing;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```